# Is is possible to mqtt client with 100k concurrent session on a single computer

Tags: node.js, winforms, ubuntu, jmeter, erlang

I am testing mqtt broker for bench marking with various opensource githubprojects written in go, models, erlang and jmeter tool for 100k concurrent clients.

Mqtt stresser : https://github.com/inovex/mqtt-stresser

Nodejs benchmark client:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-benchmark

Jmeter

Erlang mqtt broker bench mark tool:  https://github.com/emqtt/emqtt_benchmark

But all these clients are able to send around 64 000 after that it will fail.  I'm using windows operating system and same thing happens in ubuntu also.  Does it requires some tuning?

Comment: The OS shouldn't be the issue. The number of CPU cores and memory does affect the throughput though. Have you tried to do the same test on a machine with more cores / memory and compare results?

Answer (score 0):

If each session is using a separate TCP port then you will run out of ports when you get to around 65535 (minus 1024 since only root can use ports 0-1024) since the that is the total range of TCP ports.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)